# Minify and compile single file using Gulp

Tags: javascript, php, gulp, gulp-minify

There is a 1-pager website. It consists of `index.php` that includes numerous sections (other PHP files). Each of the section includes links to JavaScript files.

---

**Questions:** is it possible to generate a single minified PHP file, that will have a single link to a single minified JS file (something similar to `https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to resolve this issue myself. It is possible to achieve the desired result with just 2 tools:

- [Gulp Concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat)
- [Gulp Handle Bar Include](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-handlebars-file-include)

With **concat** I was able to concatenate all *.js files into `logic.js` like this:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/**/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('logic.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});
```

With **ghfi** I was able to include all included PHPs and then **minify** the result into a single `index.php`:

```
gulp.task('php', function () {
    gulp.src('src/index.php')
        .pipe(gulpHandlebarsFileInclude())
        .pipe(htmlmin({
            collapseWhitespace: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Had to include child-PHP files indside the parent one like this:

`{{ fileInclude 'src/foo.php' }}`

**PS:** the person who down-voted my question - you are truly <s>amazing</s>.

Answer (score 2):

Not out of box, but you can use static site generators like Jekyll, Harp.

This might require to drop php templating for something like liquid, and this way Jekyll CLI can interpret your includes and general page structure and generate ready-to-push html files that can be minified by gulp task.

[Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/)

[Harpjs](http://harpjs.com/)

[gulp-htmlmin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-htmlmin)

On a side note: if you are concerned about performance, minifying html is rarely seen as gain is marginable, especially if your server has `gzip` enabled on.